# how to write data in specific row in CSV file

Tags: python, csv

Currently I have a `csv` file in which the last column, which we can refer to as `label`, is empty. Here is a picture of the data:
[image]

I get predictions through a classifier:

```
[0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
```

Thus my question is how to write these predictions into the last column (`label`)?

Answer (score 1):

Potentially one of the easiest solutions would be to read your data in using pandas.

```
my_dataframe = pandas.read_csv("filename")
```

Then assuming your label column is some kind of list/array or even pandas series, you can simply enter

```
my_dataframe["label"] = my_label_list
```

subsequently you write back your pandas dataframe using

```
my_dataframe.to_csv("filename_out")
```

NOTE: I omitted additional parameter arguments for reading and writing the csv, you can google and read the docs and add them as you see fit.

Comment: It works! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should read your data from csv file without the last column

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['domain_name_length', 'domain_name_enthropy', 'digit_num', 'alpha_num', 'delimiter_num', 'special_num','max_conitous_digit_length','max_conitous_alpha_length','max_length_between_delimeter'])
```

Than just add your column

```
df['labels'] = labels
```

Comment: It works! thank you!